# How to use an extension method in multiple projects

Tags: vb.net, enums, extension-methods

I have an extension method that is supposed to retrieve the Description attribute value of an enum and return the string associated with the attribute. Here is the code:

```
<Extension()>
Public Function GetEnumDescription(Of T)(ByVal e As T) As String
    If e.GetType().IsEnum Then

        Dim type As Type = e.GetType()
        Dim values As Array = [Enum].GetValues(type)

        For Each Val As Integer In values
            If Val = Convert.ToInt32(e) Then
                Dim memInfo = type.GetMember(type.GetEnumName(Val))
                Dim descriptionAttribute As DescriptionAttribute = memInfo(0).GetCustomAttributes((New DescriptionAttribute).GetType(), False).FirstOrDefault()

                If descriptionAttribute IsNot Nothing Then
                    Return descriptionAttribute.Description
                End If
            End If
        Next

        Return String.Empty
    End If

    Throw New InvalidOperationException("Caller is not an Enum")
End Function
```

It works like a charm when I'm using it in the various classes defined in the same project. However, when I am working in another project (same solution, let's call it ProjectB) and I import the project that contains this extension method (ProjectA) and try to use it, it doesn't work.

So say I have an enum called MyEnum declared in ProjectB. Set up like this:

```
Public Enum MyEnum
    <Description("This is value1's description")> value1
    <Description("This is value2's description")> value2
End Enum
```

I'm working on a class in ProjectB that uses MyEnum and I want to get the value of the description attribute. I add a reference to ProjectA in ProjectB and then add the Import statement to use ProjectB in my class. When I try and do something like this:

```
Dim val As MyEnum = MyEnum.value1
MessageBox.Show(val.GetEnumDescription())
```

I expect to see a message box that says "This is value1's description", but instead I get an error that says

> 'GetEnumDescription' is not a member of 'MyEnum'

So my question is how can I use the extension method I defined in ProjectA for Enums in other projects?

Comment: That code looks fine to me.  Is the .Net version on ProjectA higher than that of ProjectB?

Comment: Code files can be "linked".  Store them somewhere unrelated to any project.  Then when adding them to a project, use the drop down list on the `Add` button (in the FileOpenDialog) to **Add as Link**

Comment: @N0Alias, both projects are targeting .NET Framework 4.

Comment: @Plutonix, I tried moving the Module with the extension to a neutral location and adding a link to it in my projects like you suggested. Problem is, the GetEnumDescription() function no longer works. When it gets to the line `Dim descriptionAttribute As DescriptionAttribute = memInfo(0).GetCustomAttributes((New DescriptionAttribute).GetType(), False).FirstOrDefault()` it throws this error: **Public member 'FirstOrDefault' on type 'DescriptionAttribute()' not found.**

Comment: You can create topical sets of extensions (such as for DateTime, Sorting, Imaging etc) which are linked in as I described as needed for this varying projects.  It was exactly what you asked about (project to project) so I didnt post a full answer.  The missing member just means an import was missing.

Answer (score 4):

I figured out my problem. When I declared the module ExtensionMethods, I didn't put an access modifier on it, so it defaulted to "Friend". Adding the "Public" access modifier to the module declaration exposed it to other projects. Silly me :/